# Completely confused: Weird behavior with spring 3.0.5 Autowiring

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, sitemesh, wurfl

i've been banging my head all day long with a very simple autowiring issue. Sorry in advance about posting about this very simplistic issue. I'm running a web application with Spring 3.0.5 with MVC where the servlet context is `my-servlet.xml` separated from the application config `webapp-config.xml` which have all the hibernate stuffs.

Basically what I am trying to do is to wire `wurfl manager` to a custom `sitemesh Decorator`. this is not related to sitemesh or wurfl am just given as much info as possible.
here is the snippet of the part:

```
public class MDecoratorMapper extends ConfigDecoratorMapper{
private String decoratorName = null;
@Autowired
WURFLManager wurflManager; // does not work, object is null
private Properties prop;
.........
}
```

my application config `webapp-config.xml` is like so :

```
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/model-config.xml"/>
<import resource="webapp-security.xml"/>
<import resource="wurfl.xml" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/><!-- this is needed by apache shiro in spring-->

<context:component-scan base-package="com.bla.bla.web.controller.admin"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bla.bla.web.controller.exception"/>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:m.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:m.log4j.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now take for example in `webapp-security.xml` there is this `hibernateRealm class` wired as such :

```
<bean id="hibernateRealm" class="com.bla.bla.web.security.HibernateRealm">
    <constructor-arg  ref="credMatcher"/>
</bean>
```

its code is here :

```
public class HibernateRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HibernateRealm.class);

@Autowired
UserAccountService uAS; // this works no problem
@Autowired
RoleService roleService; // this also works
//.....
}
```

the autowiring in this case works perfectly, never have any problem with it.

Now let's take this context file : `wurfl.xml` it has [click here to see](http://pastie.org/3985028)

```
 <bean id="mDecoratorMapper" class="com.bla.bla.web.decoratormapper.MDecoratorMapper">
    <!--<property name="wurflManager" ref="wurfl.manager"/>-->
</bean>
```

its code is here :

```
public class MDecoratorMapper extends ConfigDecoratorMapper{
private String decoratorName = null;
@Autowired
WURFLManager wurflManager; <!--this always return null-->
private Properties prop;

public void init(Config config, Properties properties, DecoratorMapper parent) throws InstantiationException {
    super.init(config, properties, parent);
    this.prop = properties;
//decoratorName = properties.getProperty("decorator.name", "mobile");
// ....
}
```

It's all become weird to me.so i decided to autowire it inside a Controller. and it wasn't null.I really don't have any explanation for this .i even used as you can see the commented property , that i've also use property wiring.

I don't get it ,and am locked right now staring at my timeline. I would be really grateful if someone give a hand. Thanks for reading this

**EDIT :**

to add to my astonishment i've switched back to the default ConigDecoratorMapper to get the site going and added the WURFLManager to a MVC controller :

```
@Controller(value = "useraccesscontroller")
```

//@RequestMapping("/site/authentication")
public class UserAccessController {

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserAccessController.class);

@Autowired
UserAccountService userAccountService;
@Autowired
VerificationService verificationService;
@Autowired
EmailSender emailSender;
@Autowired
EmailTemplateService emailTemplateService;

@Autowired
Map<String, String> facebookAPI;
@Resource
@Qualifier(value = "roleLandingPage")
Map<String, String> roleLandingPage;
@Resource
@Qualifier(value = "usefulUrls")
Map<String, String> usefulUrls;
@Autowired
private WURFLManager wurflManager;


public UserAccessController(){

}


@RequestMapping(value = "/site/authentication/signup/form")
public ModelAndView showAccountRequestForm(HttpServletRequest request){
    net.sourceforge.wurfl.core.Device device = wurflManager.getDeviceForRequest(request);
    SignupForm form = new SignupForm();
    ModelMap map = new ModelMap();
    map.addAttribute("signupForm",form);
    map.addAttribute("message","");

    return new ModelAndView("signup",map);

}
```

I can attest that this autowiring inside the UserAccessController works and during debugging i tested with `User-Agent Switcher for Chrome` and it's picking the device.so why not in my Decorator :(

Comment: In your code, I do no see wurfl.manager bean definition in the xml configuration, it is there? If dont, it is WURFLManager marked as @service?

Comment: i've added a pastie link to show what i have inside wurfl.xml. i've left all the commented stuff maybe am doing some wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your `wurfl.manager` as autowired candidate

```
<bean id="wurfl.manager" class="net.sourceforge.wurfl.spring.SpringWurflManager" autowire-candidate="true">
     <property name="wurflModel" ref="wurfl.model" />
</bean>
```

Also, notice that `net.sourceforge.wurfl.spring` packake is not being scanned by Spring according with your configuration

Updated:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="net.sourceforge.wurfl.*"/>
```

Comment: Hello  thanks for the tip, i've added the component-scan for net.sourceforge.wurfl.spring but still having null pointer exception.i've updated the wurfl.xml

Comment: Did you add wurfl.xml to the Spring web.xml configuration so it is loaded by Spring? Edit: well, i see you are importing it. Change you packaging scanning as I described above

Comment: Hi, thanks for your .currently in a cat going home.will test in an hour time and  revert thanks

Comment: It's look like Spring cannot find your bean. Let's try to move your wurfl.xml file content to webapp-config.xml and see if the problem is that wurfl.xml is not loaded by Spring.

Comment: with the same config i would get the WURFLManager wired into any Controller. that's the part i am trying to pay attention to. nothing so far.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how your custom `MDecoratorMapper` is used. I haven't used SiteMesh in a very long time, but I expect that a `ConfigDecoratorMapper` is a Sitemesh class whose lifecycle is controlled by SiteMesh, not by Spring. Therefore, why do you expect it to get an injected instance? How are you telling SiteMesh to use the `MDecoratorMapper`? It's only going to get one that's been injected if it's going to Spring to get it (or if you're using AspectJ bytecode weaving).

Comment: Hello @Ryan, i've updated the pastie link in the post you can see it here http://pastie.org/3985028 thanks

Comment: Okay, so that just confirms what I said, right? SiteMesh is the one creating your decorator mapper. Spring doesn't even come into the picture. I'm no SiteMesh expert, as I mentioned, so I don't know what kind of options you might have for SiteMesh/Spring integration. The one thing I know of that would work is the [AspectJ bytecode weaving I mentioned](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable).